# CakePhp- save method while saving data from a Form

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have faced this error while saving data from a form.

> **"Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object in H:\wamp\www\onlineblog\app\Controller\PostsController.php on line 23"**

Here is the **add** methos PostsController.

```
public  function  add(){
   if($this->request->is('post')){
      $this->loadModel('Post');
      if($this->set->Post->save($this->request->data)){
        $this->Session->setFlash("Post added successfully");
          $this->redirect(array('action'=>'hello_cake'));
      }
       else{
           $this->Session->setFlash("Post Can't be added");
       }
   }
}
```

and here is the add view

```
<h2>Add a Post</h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post',array('action'=>'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('heading');
echo $this->Form->input('body');
echo $this->Form->end('Create a Post');

?>
```

Comment: which version of cakephp you are using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$this->Post->save(
```

Instead of this:

```
$this->set->Post->save(
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this I think that will work.

```
public  function  add(){
   if($this->request->is('post')){
      $this->Post->create();
      if($this->Post->save($this->request->data)){
          $this->Session->setFlash("Post added successfully");
          $this->redirect(array('action'=>'hello_cake'));
      }
       else{
           $this->Session->setFlash("Post Can't be added");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you just dump code - it is not always obvious what you've changed. _Always_ provide an explanation.